# Precision of the root using bisection method

Tags: numerical-methods

It is known that the root of the function $f(x)$ lies between $0$ and $1$. After $10$ iterations of the bisection method, what will be the approximate precision of the root?

Comment: Please provide more details, for instance, what are your thoughts about the question, what you have tried, where you are stuck.

Comment: every iteration of bisection shrinks the interval containing the root by half. So after ten iteration, if you didn't accidentally find the root, the interval contains the root has length $2^{-10}$.